# VNC Server with invitation mode

Tags: vnc, remote-access, realvnc

I often use RealVNC to access my home computer while I'm away.

But sometimes I'm working on my home computer and I want to give a remote colleague temporary access to manipulate my computer.

So I can give him my VNC password, but... It's secret! So I have to change it to a temporary password, give that to him, and then change it back. Cumbersome!

What I really want is to be able to give people a one-time invitation to control my computer.

Does RealVNC offer that option?

I know that Microsoft's tool has that, but it's cumbersome in its own right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it doesn't.  Nor is there anything built into the vnc protocol to provides that sort of feature.  VNC is very basic and built to do one thing -- share the desktop and provide KVM. The citrix products like Gotomeeting and Gotomypc offer these features but of course they aren't free.  Based on your description of how you conduct these sessions, you might want to try out https://join.me/ which is a service similar to gotomeeting, from logmein, and has a "free" version that might work for you.

Comment: I never said I was limiting myself to free products.

Comment: In that case I would highly recommend gotomypc or gotomeeting.  For microsoft PC operating systems, nothing works as well as the citrix products since they literally wrote the book on windows os remote control, and created terminal server for microsoft. I have used vnc quite a bit, and it's certainly usable, but it pales in comparison performance wise to remote desktop because remote desktop is able to take advantage of windows os internals to get high performance.

Comment: My experiences with Citrix had so far been abysmal, so I think I'll avoid. Plus, their price is monthly, like a service! I prefer to pay for a program one time and then be able to use it forever.

Comment: I can't speak to that, especially since you didn't provide any details.  Citrix has the best performance, and all sorts of features, but it is a service, and is certainly not aiming to be the cheapest in the marketplace.  Other products and services get the job done, albeit with slower performance.  There isn't a product I know of that you purchase a license for that has the specific feature you were looking for, of facilitating "guest" passwords or one-time passwords, and I think I've used nearly every product that has come out, stretching back to the pre norton pcanwhere/carbon copy days.